# Xamarin Android Support Library 23.4.0.1 (Vector Drawables)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

While trying to set a compound drawable (drawable left) of an EditText, I'm having an issue using vector drawables on Android 4.3. I have my ic_mobile.xml (svg) wrapped in a state list.

This Works on Android 5.0 + . It used to work on 4.3. But it stopped working recently. I know Android disabled Vector drawables and you have to manually re-enable them

```
AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
```

But I'm still seeing this error

```
Invalid drawable tag Vector.
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-Xamarin answer, I hope it will help you. When you create the drawable, create it as a `VectorDrawable`. Now, to support older platforms (4.3) you can use `VectorDrawableCompat.create(...)`. Don't try to create a plain drawable, because, as stated in the error, the tag `<vector>` is not supported on all SDKs.
Unfortunately, I don't know what are the equivalent classes in Xamarin, but it should be fairly simple to pick it up from here.

Comment: thank you! that's what i ended up doing. but the tent is off...i'm using a black vector image. When i tint it though the xml, the tint colour is applied correctly , but when i tint it though code, it's adding it over the black colour. Any hints? probably something with the Tint mode..

Comment: No hints, since I don't know how you're tinting it :-) Share some code?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by doing everything in code

```
private VectorDrawableCompat _phoneVectorDrawable;
_phoneVectorDrawable = VectorDrawableUtil.GetTintedDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_mobile, _tintColor_darkColor, Theme);
```

Where ic_mobile is a vector drawable (.xml)

You can use it as a compound drawable like this

```
 _EditTextMobileNumber.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(_phoneVectorDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Tested and working on Android 4.3 to 6.0. I think this is a Xamarin specific issue.

Comment: Upgrading the Xamarin support libraries to 25.1.1 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @LukePothier glad you got it sorted! I'll upgrade and test! cheers